# Import CSV - Escape of the characteristics colon

Tags: csv, import, escaping, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to import products on the prestashop backoffice using the CSV import, but, I have some difficulties with the characteristics of the products.

In the documentation it's explained that it's possible to add the characteristics according to the following description : (Name: Value: Position: Custom).

The names of my characteristics contain the character ":" as ("ASPECT: Colors" for example). The cell in my CSV file looks like this:

`ASPECT: Colors: White`

How can I import my products without changing the name of my features on Prestashop?

I have already looked at the escape characters like "\" or "\" but didn"t work. And when I use double quote, prestashop add a new Caraterisitc named : `"ASPECT` with value : `Colors"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to escape string content to prevent it from CSV parsing is put it into quotation marks. In your case it will be like this:

```
"ASPECT: Colors": White
```

Note: as there is no CSV standard exists, reading part may fail to recognize particular escaping techniques.

It already seems to be non-standard to me as it uses colons ":" instead of comma "," separators, as file name implies.

Comment: I have already tryed this method and prestashop add a new Caraterisitc named : `"ASPECT` with value : `Colors"`

Comment: Are you using this prestashop? https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop

Comment: Quick look at source code suggests to me that they have a proper CSV parser, which delimits entries with ";" and supports string escape with double quotes. Where did you get your odd syntax?

Comment: Yes I use this prestashop well (1.6). In the prestashop documentation for the CSV import, the characteristics must be in the form: Characteristic (Name: Value: Position: Custom). And in my value "Name" contains character ":" which does not escape. I have alredy tryed the following test : "ASPECT : Colors":white and ASPECT ":" Colors:white but don't work. I obtain odd value into the backoffice characteristic

Comment: @DevLoots As you have PrestaShop PHP code deployed on your server already, why not you just change that part which deals with import and replace ":" with some other character.